# Await for an object creation

Tags: rust, async-await, future

In Rust I need to multiple times await till an object is created or return object immediately if it is already created.

If I use plain future, it does not work, because a future can be awaited only once.

Fused future is also not an option, because `Fuse` returns pending at the second call.

So, what to use?

Comment: Something like [`tokio::sync::OnceCell`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/struct.OnceCell.html)?

Comment: Looks like you want to call the function that returns the future again and again.